# How to find the differential of a function of two variables going from Δf to df?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

[image]

When finding $dP$, why there is no more $ΔV$ in the first bracket? (In other words, Why did the author removed $ΔV$ when he went from $ΔP$ to $dp$?)

Comment: This is black magic addressed to thermodynamics 101 students, and is not meant to be a serious mathematical argument.

Comment: Yes, it is a page from a physical chemistry textbook (Mcquaire book), but my question is not about the thermodynamic concept, my question is about the mathematics involved, like is there something I am not seeing or I don't know in calculus to get what is written in this page. Or maybe it is wrong in the book.
It is a page from a chapter titled: "Mathchapter H partial differential".
It is serious for me. Anyway, thanks for your help.